# Set body width,same as clients window

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

What i'm looking for,is a way to set the width of the body same as the clients window's,using JAVA.
This code i've borrowed from W3S,but its not working in my case -

```js
function body_width(w)
{

var w = window.innerWidth
|| document.documentElement.clientWidth
|| document.body.clientWidth;

var x = document.body;
x.style.width = w;

}

window.onload = body_width(w);
```

Also i've gave `"style="width:;" "` to the body

Comment: Java**Script**. Not Java

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using screen.availWidth and screen.availHeight?

*The screen.availHeight property returns the height of the visitor's screen, in pixels, minus interface features like the Windows Taskbar.*

*The screen.availWidth property returns the width of the visitor's screen, in pixels, minus interface features like the Windows Taskbar.*

It could be done easily with Viewport-Percentage Lengths:

*The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.*

**HTML**

```html
<div>Your Container</div>
```

**And CSS**

```css
div {
        height:100vh;
    }
```

That is all you need.

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uz9pu8by/) example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set width in % :

```
<style>
Body{
   width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

not `window.onload = body_width(w);`

its `window.onload = body_width;`

Answer (score 0):

This option worked out perfectly.

```js
<script>
function body_width(w)
{

var w = screen.availWidth
var x = document.body;
x.style.width = screen.availWidth + "px";

}

window.onload = body_width;
</script>
```

Thanks 2 ivarz_LV

Answer (score 0):

When I tested, using

```
body {
 height: 100%;
}
```

won't work. Try using this in `style`:

```
body {
 height: 100vh;
}
```

I figured using `vh` would work better.